# Return Different Types Within One Function C#

Tags: c#, generics, types, return-type

I am creating a project data pipeline and I need to return different types from a single class

in this class I have a number of Dictionaries that hold and separate the elements/content i want to load up but i need a way to return them with a single string... as i am not to familiar with these Type functions i am lost as to how to return the content properly

I need this in a separate class so i can do a XML serialization later

Here is what I have now

```
DataClass contents;
public T ReturnType<T>(string asset)
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {
        return contents.Integers[Asset];
    }
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(float))
    {
        return contents.Floats[Asset];
    }
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(double))
    {
        return contents.Doubles[Asset];
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

it will allow me to use a base Object class to parse the content but i dont want anything to get lost in transit so i am weary in using this method

my question is how to return one of the different objects of a certain types within the class that i am using for serialization with a function like that

If i wanted to use the previous function to grab content within the class eg

```
public Object someobject;
//button event handler to change the current object
//preferably this would be changed depending on the object i would be calling
//but this should do for showing how it is supposed to work
public void ChangeCurrentObject(event e)
{
    someobject = (Object)ReturnType<Object>("23rdObject");
}
```

it sends a string to the function called 'ReturnType' and returns an object ie(int, float,etc) within there own respective dictionary

Comment: I will have to apologize I am self taught and as such my terminology is horrendous

Comment: you may try to change the declaration of DataClass to be able to get `Contents[typeof(T)][Asset]`

Comment: I don't see a question....If you know your terminology look up the correct terminology.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What you did there should work fine, or does it not?

Comment: If your code is not generally generic, it's probably not a good idea to use generics. Here, the effort of all the type-checking outweighs the effort of providing specific methods for each type, reduces readability and ultimately *reduces* the type-safety of your code (what happens when your generic method is called with an unexpected type? Does the other end expect a `default(T)`? What happens if I request an Asset using the wrong type T?). Sack the generics... this use is not what they are designed for.

Comment: I agree with @spender. Also, the way your ReturnType<T> is now, `int a=ReturnType("test");` would not work and you would need to specify the type in the call anyway, like `int a=ReturnType<int>("test")`. I can't see any advantage over having different non-generic methods `int ReturnInt(string asset)`, `float ReturnFloat(string asset)`...

Comment: @PaoloFalabella: If the caller of the method has a generic parameter of type `T`, it may be useful for that caller to be able to call `ReturnType<T>("whatever")` without having to worry about what type `T` is.  That having been said, there are better ways of writing `ReturnType<T>` so as to avoid testing the type of `T` each time it's run.

Comment: lists use something like this to create different types of list... and XNA uses something like this for their content pipeline
if you wanted to make a new list of integers it would be like this
public int List<int>()
and in XNA thay have a load function T Load<T>(string asset)
witch when called looks something like this
Model Load<Model>("Foobar")

Answer (score 0):

The generics in this case will only help you not to write diferent method for every asset type. You can also use this aproach to make it more modular.

```
     static  class Assets
    {
        public interface IAssetHandler<out T> 
        {
            T GetAsset(string name);
        }

        private static readonly Dictionary<Type,object> _handlers=new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        public static T GetAsset<T>(string name)
        {

            object assetHandler;

            if(!_handlers.TryGetValue(typeof(T),out assetHandler))
            {
              throw  new Exception("No handler for that type of asset");
            }

            return (assetHandler as IAssetHandler<T>).GetAsset(name);

        }


        public static void RegisterAssetHandler<T>(IAssetHandler<T> handler)
        {
            _handlers[typeof (T)] = handler;
        }

    }


 public class IntAssetsHandler:Assets.IAssetHandler<int>
        {
            #region Implementation of IAssetHandler<out int>

            public int GetAsset(string name)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            #endregion
        }





        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assets.RegisterAssetHandler(new IntAssetsHandler());

            Console.WriteLine(Assets.GetAsset<int>("test"));


        }
```

Comment: this almost answers the problem... it is only half of the function though the problem is returning the actual content with varying types

Comment: Just implement one handler for each type you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

You could use external class, set the properties types as you wish, then use it in your function.

```
public class MultipleOpjects
{
    public List<string> ObjectOne { get; set; }

    public List<object> ObjectTwo { get; set; }

    public object ObjectThree { get; set; }

}
public MultipleOpjects GetAnything()
{
    MultipleOpjects Vrble = new MultipleOpjects();
    Vrble.ObjectOne  = SomeThing1;
    Vrble.ObjectTwo = SomeThing2;
    Vrble.ObjectThree = SomeThing3;

    return Vrble;      
}
```